# How do I share data between worker processes in Elixir?

Tags: networking, erlang, udp, elixir

I have 2 workers

```
worker(Mmoserver.MessageReceiver, []),
worker(Mmoserver.Main, [])
```

The MessageReceiver will wait until messages are received on TCP and process them, the Main loop will take that information and act on it. How do I share the info obtained by worker1 with worker2?

**Mmoserver.ex**
This is the main file that starts the workers

```
defmodule Mmoserver do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    IO.puts "Listening for packets..."

    children = [
      # We will add our children here later

      worker(Mmoserver.MessageReceiver, []),
      worker(Mmoserver.Main, [])
    ]

    # Start the main supervisor, and restart failed children individually
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: AcmeUdpLogger.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

end
```

**MessageReceiver.ex**
This will just start a tcp listener. It should be able to get a message, figure out what it is (by it's id) then parse data and send it to a specific function in Main

```
defmodule Mmoserver.MessageReceiver do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
  end

  def init (:ok) do
    {:ok, _socket} = :gen_udp.open(21337)
  end

  # Handle UDP data
  def handle_info({:udp, _socket, _ip, _port, data}, state) do
    parse_packet(data)
    # Logger.info "Received a secret message! " <> inspect(message)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  # Ignore everything else
  def handle_info({_, _socket}, state) do
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def parse_packet(data) do
    # Convert data to string, then split all data
    # WARNING - SPLIT MAY BE EXPENSIVE
    dataString = Kernel.inspect(data)
    vars = String.split(dataString, ",")

    # Get variables
    packetID = Enum.at(vars, 0)
    x = Enum.at(vars, 1)

    # Do stuff with them
    IO.puts "Packet ID:"
    IO.puts packetID
    IO.puts x

    # send data to main
    Mmoserver.Main.handle_data(vars)
  end
end
```

**Main.ex**
This is the main loop. It will process all the most recent data received by the tcp listener and act on it. Eventually it will update the game state too.

```
defmodule Mmoserver.Main do
  use GenServer

  @tickDelay 33

  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: Main)
  end

  def init (state) do

    IO.puts "Main Server Loop started..."

    # start the main loop, parameter is the initial tick value
    mainLoop(0)

    # return, why 1??
    {:ok, 1}
  end

  def handle_data(data) do
    GenServer.cast(:main, {:handle_data, data})
  end

  def handle_info({:handle_data, data}, state) do
    # my_function(data)
    IO.puts "Got here2"
    IO.puts inspect(data)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  # calls respective game functions
  def mainLoop(-1) do
    IO.inspect "Server Loop has ended!" # base case, end of loop
  end

  def mainLoop(times) do
    # do shit
    # IO.inspect(times) # operation, or body of for loop

    # sleep
    :timer.sleep(@tickDelay);

    # continue the loop RECURSIVELY
    mainLoop(times + 1)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Mmoserver.MessageReceiver` is going to send messages to `Mmoserver.Main`, *Main* has to be started in first place, plus, it needs to have name associated:

```
worker(Mmoserver.Main, []),
worker(Mmoserver.MessageReceiver, [])
```

The easiest way could be, in your `Mmoserver.Main`, assuming it is a `GenServer`:

```
defmodule Mmoserver.Main do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: :main)
  end

  # ...
end
```

You can add convenience function, plus the implementation one like:

```
defmodule Mmoserver.Main do
  # ...

  def handle_data(data) do
    GenServer.cast(:main, {:handle_data, data})
  end

  def handle_info({:handle_data, data}, state) do
    my_function(data)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

So, your `MessageReceiver`, can send a message like:

```
defmodule Mmoserver.MessageReceiver do
  def when_data_received(data) do
    Mmoserver.Main.handle_data(data)
  end
end
```

This assumes `Mmoserver.MessageReceiver` doesn't expect `Mmoserver.Main` to respond. I've decided to do it this way as you didn't specify the way you want to handle the data and this seems the easies example of how to do this.

Comment: May also be worth mentioning looking into `GenStage` as a possibility.

Comment: This looks like it might work, but the udp listener won't work unless it's called first. This probably has to do with the fact that Main starts a loop that doesn't break. I put the calls back in the order I had them and the udp listener works, and when a message comes through handle_data is callend but NOT handle_info. Not sure why, I just put the code in my post just now

Comment: It also worries me that main is blocking the tcp listener because I need both processes to be asynchronous.